# jquery datepicker selectMonth/year css fail, conflicted with bootstrap

Tags: css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I've created the following custom ui: [custom jquery ui](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/#!zThemeParams=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)

im importing every single css file from this folder.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/jqueryUi/jquery-ui.theme.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/jqueryUi/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/jqueryUi/jquery-ui.structure.css" />
```

Problem is that my month/year select has no design and text is blank unless I hover it.

[image]

Any suggestions would be appreciated, also, if information is missing, ill provide.

**EDIT**

I dont want to "put a bandage" on it and just fix the design myself, I want the select to use the custom ui, like any other input type..

When I inspect the element I don't see too many conflicts, but what I do see is some color properties such as border,background,color etc that are grayed out (In chrome).

**Found half of the answer**

bootstrap.min.css is conflicted with the jquery-ui design.. any suggestion to let jquery-ui get priority in this?

Comment: If I had to guess, it's because Comic Sans is detected.

Comment: what do you mean? because I only use in Cursive font-family?

Comment: Sorry, I was just making a joke.

Comment: just got it...thanks for making me feel like a moron :)

Comment: give an example fiddle so that we can track

Comment: too many css/js files to upload and i have nowhere to upload it to.

Comment: ok but i just tried with those 3 css files it works fine for me

Comment: with or wiithout using selectmenu() ? in what order have you tried using them?

Comment: `$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true
    });
  });`

Comment: what is the order of the css scripts?

Comment: you can add you jquery code which you are using so that i can test that

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.structure.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.theme.min.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>`

Comment: i wrote the exact same thing.. even the css order is the same

Comment: Ok, found the problem...bootstrap is conflicted with it
the file: bootstrap.min.css.
any suggestions?

Comment: load it after bootstrap then. if its very specific and then write your own to change

Comment: I am, i already tried it. still the same

Comment: if you can give your site link

Comment: its local..ill upload to git and give a link

Comment: where do you have the datepicker issue. I opened the main page and datepicker seems fine. may be you have the clear the cache

Comment: I fixed it :) i uploaded a fix there

Answer (score 0):

Your month/year select text is having white color that is the reason it is not visible so just change select text color it will be visible.

Comment: I know that is white, i dont want to put a bandage on it, the custom ui isn't applied on it. i want to know why..

Answer (score 0):

Solved the conflict with the select,
ran a search of 'select' in bootstrap.css and deleted each reference.